# xxx.sh: : not found

Tags: shell-script, busybox, adb

I'm debugging a shell script and coming across this error. I have no idea what's going on with my script.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

function SetEQ(){
    prefFile='/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
# a comment line that was deleted by me, sorry for that.

    case $1 in
            speaker) array=(0.0 0.0 0.0 -3.64 -10.66 -15.0 -6.49 0.0) ;;
            samsung) array=(0.0 2.9 0.0 -1.5 -6.4 2.7 0.0 0.0) ;;
                  *) exit ;;
    esac

    for i in ${!array[@]}; do
            sed -ir "s/(\"com.smp.equalizer.$i\" value=\")[^\"]*(\")/\1${array[$i]}\2/" "$prefFile"
    done
}

SetEQ samsung
```

When I run the script by: `# sh -vx ./test2.sh`

The debug information is as follows:

```
+ SetEQ samsung
+ prefFile='/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
+ set -A array -- 0.0 2.9 0.0 -1.5 -6.4 2.7 0.0 0.0
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.0" value=")[^"]*(")/\10.0\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.1" value=")[^"]*(")/\12.9\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.2" value=")[^"]*(")/\10.0\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.3" value=")[^"]*(")/\1-1.5\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-353/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.4" value=")[^"]*(")/\1-6.4\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-353/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.5" value=")[^"]*(")/\12.7\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.6" value=")[^"]*(")/\10.0\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
+   sed -ir 's/("com.smp.equalizer.7" value=")[^"]*(")/\10.0\2/' '/mnt/media_rw/6633-3539/tmpFiles/com.smp.musicspeed_preferences.xml'
./test2.sh[18]: : not found
```

I have to say that the `sed` lines have no issue when I run them directly in the terminal. The debug information is very vague, what is not found? The command? The script file? The paths given to `sed`?

**EDIT: @Paul_Pedant was right, I forgot to have copyed the sed line to Windows system than paste them back to VI. After re-enter the line by hand, the problem solved!**

Comment: Please first check that none of the files you use here have Windows-style line endings (CR-LF). The output `: : not found` is commonly caused by an informative message being garbled because it partly over-writes itself.

Comment: The line number (18) doesn't seem to correspond to anything in the script that you are showing.  Is this a `ksh` script (because it's certainly not Busybox `sh`)? It's often generally better to do XML processing using XML-aware tools, and `sed` is not one of them. However, this does not have much to do with the problem at hand. Are you using Busybox `sed`? What happens if you separate the `-i` and `-r` options (the `r` would otherwise be taken as the option argument of `-i`)? Not that it solves your issue, mind you, just a comment on the code. The is likely it being a DOS text file

Comment: You could also pass the script through shellcheck.net. Error messages that reference the line after the actual last one are generally caused by an unterminated syntax element (quoted string, unmatched braces etc).

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I deleted a comment line before posting, hence the [18]. I wrote the script under adb shell, and the `echo $SHELL` command output the result `/system/bin/sh`. I certainly prefer other stronger shells if the system has one. And I wonder if there is a XML-aware tool under adb shell environment.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't code that can be run with `sh` as it contains references to arrays. It might be `bash` or it might be `ksh`, but it's definitely not `sh`.

Comment: The script is written under adb shell. When checking with command `echo $SHELL`, the result is `/system/bin/sh`.

Comment: @preachers ah, it seems it may be a variant of `ksh`